# A web site with embedded remote control capabilities

Tags: asp.net, remote-access

We're going to develop the service desk web site, which will allow the customer service representatives to log in, see the list of customers assigned to them, be able to remote access their computer (by negotiation with the customer) and then report the information about the service issue into the CRM. The software will need to track the number of time intervals (e.g. 15 minutes intervals) the CSR was online with customer. So, what we're looking for is some "embeddable" remote management software (something like logmein.com, but which will have an API and can be embedded into another web application and send such events as - connected/disconnected, accept the host that needs to be connected information etc.) Does anyone have any ideas about that?

Comment: You would do probably better to have a service that runs on the clients, that monitors how long the process to remote connect was active, which then uses soap to report back to the helpdesk.

Comment: any ideas about *which part*?  is this just a really long version of "are there any good available remote management software sdks available"?

Comment: @John - This is not just a remote management software. This needs to be embedded with MS Dynamic CRM and some accounting software. So, the remote access software needs to be actually embedded as a part of the custom web application that we will develop.

Comment: @BugFinder - it won't be possible to deliver to clients ANY custom software. Clients might accept the LogMeIn connection or something like TeamViewer, but not actually a customly written application, which should reside on their side all the time

Comment: @BugFinder - you know, I will probably change the mind. Yes, I think client CAN download some tool, which, for example, will embed some remote management software and will be able to send notification to the server about the airtime. The only problem here would be to give a client ability to accept the connection when they're behind the firewall. So, yes, it can be rephrased into the question - "Are there any good available remote management software SDKs available?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have network connectivity and permissions, the Microsoft Remote Desktop client app can be embedded in a web page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383541(VS.85).aspx